# THREE.OrbitControls effect on scene object rotations

Tags: javascript, three.js

Just started to learn THREE.js and i've made a simple scene with basic stuff:
http://codepen.io/inspiral/full/Lewgj

Everything works fine except a strange effect what the recently inserted mouse event handling makes with the rendering.

Here is the tutorial for mouse events i've used: 
http://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_orbit.html

What i did was that i've added reference to *OrbitControls.js* and the following code lines to my project:

```
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );
controls.damping = 0.2;
controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );
```

It works, but the more i use rotation with mouse the faster the cube and the particle cloud move.
I guess i missed to do something, but dunno what. Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have an animation loop, you do not need to call

```
controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );
```

`OrbitControls` does not have a `dampinig` property.

The reason for the speed-up is you have named your "animation loop" `render()`, and by calling

```
controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );
```

the animation loop is called whenever the mouse moves.

three.js r.69

Comment: great answer. this problem was affecting me too. thanks a lot